# how to print 2-D array row by row in GDB?

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, gdb

```
map[22][22];
```

I want to see 'map(2-D array)' by GDB and the result was like this

> $1 = {{-1 repeats 22 times}, {-1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4, -1 repeats 11 times}, {-1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, -1 repeats 11 times}, {-1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 repeats 11 times}, {-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 4, 4, 1, -1 repeats 11 times}, {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, -1 repeats 11 times}, {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1 repeats 11 times}, {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 repeats 11 times}, {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 repeats 11 times}, {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 repeats 11 times}, {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 repeats 11 times>}, {-1 repeats 22 times} repeats 11 times>}

and it was so unuseful to see..

I want to see like this

```
{-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1}

{1,2,3,4,5,2,4,}

{2,1,4,5,3,4,2,2}

...
```

can you tell how to print 2-D array row by row??

Comment: What's wrong with the output GDB shows you?  It is correct, accurate, descriptive....

Comment: @JohnZwinck It's hard to read...?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to see like this

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

1. Implement `debug_print()` function in your program, call it from GDB with the `call` command.
2. Implement Python pretty-printer. [Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing-API.html). [Tutorial](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html).

The first solution is trivial to implement, but (unlike the second) doesn't work when you don't have a live process (e.g. for `core` postmortem debugging).